# IBM MDM BusinessProxy CompositeTxn thread safety

Tags: master-data-management

Are instance level objects in IBM MDM BusinessProxy/ExternalRules/BehaviorExtension thread safe ?

If 5 threads are invoking a BusinessProxy(BP) via MQ or WebserviceCall or by BatchProcessor,then are 5 BP Objects created newly or is it just a single BP object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a POC to validate the same. I found that each time a BP is getting called a new BP object is created and hence the instance level objects are always thread safe.